# Where is the data in batch class coming from?

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup

First of all, I'm very new to salesforce so It's possible that I'm ignoring something very basic.

I was writing a test class for the following batch (I've removed all the irrelevant parts).

```
global class ExtractDataBatchLatam implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
   
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    return Database.getQueryLocator([select id, bvc__c, qty_allocated__c, adjustment__c, remaining__c, blockedAllocation__c,total_actual__c,total_forecast__c,reserveQuantity__c,final_remaining__c,salesman__r.name from allocation_line_item__c ]);

}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, list<allocation_line_item__c> aliList){

   //debugging the data in list
   system.debug('aliList from main class');
        for(allocation_line_item__c a:aliList){
            system.debug(a);
        }

   //some code to update this data

}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){}    
    //some code to send email.
}
```

The test class is as below:

```
        @isTest
        private class ExtractDataBatchTest {
        @testSetup
        static void setup() {
        
        List<allocation_line_item__c> aliList = new List<allocation_line_item__c>();
    
        primary_crop__c pc=new primary_crop__c(
        name='crop123',
        bvc__c=123456);
        insert pc;
        
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
        
        User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing6969', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser6969@testorg.com');
        insert u;

        // insert 10 records
        for (Integer i=0;i<10;i++) {
            aliList.add(new allocation_line_item__c(primary_crop__c=pc.id, 
                qty_allocated__c=60.00, 
                adjustment__c=20.00, 
                remaining__c=60.00, 
                blockedAllocation__c=10.00,
                total_actual__c=60.00,
                total_forecast__c=400.00,
                reserveQuantity__c=12.00,
                final_remaining__c=60 .00,
                salesman__c=u.id));
        }
        
        insert aliList;     
    }

    @isTest static void test() {
        Test.startTest();
        ExtractDataBatchLatam e = new ExtractDataBatchLatam();
        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(e);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

My assumption is that when I run the test and my batch class is invoked, In the debug logs, I should see the 10 dummy records that I've created in my test class . However the data I see has the same BVC field but all other fields are different. Around 20 records are logged in the debug logs (instead of 10 that I created in the test class). See screenshot below.

I'm especially concerned with the salesman__c field as all the salesmen are different while I've only created one user. Can anyone explain from where is this batch class taking data when invoked from a test class?

I can't see the screenshot for some reason, see here:
i.stack.imgur.com/ISpNw.png

Comment: Did you annotated the class with seeAllData=true? Or Any possible trigger, flow, pb which could be in action?

Comment: @Sachin Hooda No, I did not annotate the class with seeAllData=true. I also don't see any active triggers on the object. Any other ideas?

Comment: Use the Salesman__c value from the debug & see if the user actually exist.. and try debugging the list size in execute.

Comment: @Sachin Hooda Thank you for your help. I found the issue. Indeed there was a trigger on  primary crop that I overlooked that created new records.

Comment: @SachinHooda - you should post an answer